# Firefox Selenium - Input at specific index

Tags: testing, selenium

maybe i am missing something obvious but i can't make Selenium find an input on x position.

I am using Selenium IDE 1.9 on Firefox on Windows.

I have selected Command: type, target: //input[contains(@id,"txt")][3] and value: 25

However, it can't find input at third position even if i actually have three text boxes containing "txt" in the ID.

What would be the correct xpath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me, using this small HTML snippet:

```
<html>
<head />
<body>
<input id="txt1" value="TextBox 1" />
<input id="txt2" value="TextBox 2" />
<input id="txt3" value="TextBox 3" />
</body>
</html>
```

This XPath works fine:

```
//input[contains(@id,"txt")][3]
```

I suspect it may be that it could be in another IFrame, can you find objects/around it? Are you able to find any parent control of the textbox? If you take away the index, does it find anything? Have you tried putting that XPath query directly into Firebug?

Comment: The HTML in question is much more complex, so i had to find a different approach, but your answer is correct and thanks for your help!